# How download file from one folder to another in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file called `C:\skor\test.xlsx`
And I need create a copy of it in `C:\skor2\`

`pd.read_excel` and `df.to_excel` - cannot be used

Basically I need to copy the file without opening it.

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-Python)

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("C:\skor\test.xlsx", "C:\skor2\test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please include some explanation too

Answer (score 0):

**Use this.**

it will Copy the contents of the file named src to a file named dst.
**Note :->**
The destination location must be writable; otherwise, an IOError exception will be raised.
If dst already exists, it will be replaced.
src and dst are path names given as strings.

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)
```